# Is exposing enumerated id's a bad idea if precautions are taken?

Tags: attacks, authorization, websites, url

Say I have a website that has the URL `website.com/student/{studentId}/courses` for retrieving all the courses a student is enrolled in. The `studentId` is an auto-incrementing value in the `Student` table I have in my database.

Obviously I'm securing my API and returning back 403s if the user's current session doesn't match the `studentId` that they are trying to get the courses for. Is it a bad idea to directly expose these `studentId`s, or any enumerated id for that matter? Should I just take a look at using `GUID`s or some other type of randomly generated string of numbers and/or letters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But, is it a bad idea to directly expose these studentId's, or any
>   enumerated id for that matter?

If effective logic is applied to data retrieval such that each session is tied to a student ID and no one other than the session can retrieve the data about the courses he is in. In that condition, there is no problem in using incrementing ID'S in a URL such as `website.com/student/{studentId}/courses`

Comment: I disagree with your notion that the answer of Script_Junkie is wrong. He has a valid point that your answer is missing: Defense in Depth. If the "effective logic" has a bug, which is not totally impossible due to the fact that we're all humans, a GUID would provide another layer to slow down an attacker.

Comment: @mhr fair enough.Usually i dont say an answer is wrong.Why i wrote that was because of this right here "_For example, an attacker could scrap your website by using a simple script accessing /studentId1 or /studentId2_".The OP clearly says in his question that he has session controls placed in to prevent that.Secondly his answer states that returning 403 http response is another layer of security is not true.An attacker simply cant bypass that.Lastly if there is a logic flaw in the website that lets me see other peoples data that is a vulnerability and using GUID to solve that is a bad idea.

Comment: @mhr how is a GUID a control against the scraping risk?

Comment: @VipulNair thanks for the clarification - and i guess you are right in that regard ;)

Answer (score 0):

If in doubt, err on the side of caution.  In the corporate world, sequential customer id's are often obfuscated or encrypted, so as not to show how many customers the company has.

A simple way to do this without changing your database structure is send encrypted studentids (instead of the actual studentids) in all responses.  You can do this using an AES encryption function, which is probably built-in to the database that you are using.  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html.  You'll need to generate a key that your application will use for this purpose, and store it securely.  The encrypted studentids will look like a long string of hexadecimal or base64 numbers.

For requests, where the user provides a studentid, it's the opposite - the user will provide the encrypted studentid in the request, so your application will need to decrypt it first before doing whatever it does with it.

Comment: I'm curious: would switching to GUID be less resource-intensive than encrypting? Encrypting seems like a massive resource cost for this purpose.

Comment: AES is very well optimized at this point (think about the fact that most web servers encrypt *everything* that the serve, when using SSL/TLS), and the values that he's talking about are only a few bytes.  And, this saves him from having to make changes to his db structure.

Comment: Mild nitpick (although I'm largely repeating Schroeder). IDs aren't usually obfuscated or encrypted. Instead GUIDs are used in place of an auto increment, which gives much better results over all.

Comment: It wasn't clear from his question whether this is a live application in production, or an application being newly developed.  If new developed, I agree with Conor and Schroeder.  If it's a production application, and this issue became a concern, I would look for the least disruptive way to solve it, e.g. what I proposed above.

Comment: Instead of using the GUIDs there is another idea. During page processing on server, application takes the direct IDs that would need to be presented on webpage and generate one time value (can be cryptographically safe), that then are rendered on webpage. When user for example clicks on the link with such a one-time value, on server the app is looking up to the reference table in session and resolves the value to direct ID. Any time the page is referenced the value for the same direct ID should be newly generated. It looks complex but I used that for some solutions and it worked very well.

Answer (score -1):

There are many drawbacks of using auto incremental ID's in the URLs. For example, an attacker could scrape your website by using a simple script accessing /studentId1 or /studentId2 etc. Another drawback is if you have auto incremented ID's in URL it won't be difficult to find how many resources (students in your case) your website has.

Remember Security relies on the concept of Defence in Depth (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_in_depth_(computing)) and returning 403's to deter an attacker is just another layer of defence. Using GUID's in place of incremental ID's is another layer of defence that will help in case access control layer fails.

Comment: Can you explain how one could scrape the site when there is an authorisation mechanism in place to prevent exactly that? Can you also explain why knowing the number of students in the database is a risk? How difficult might it be to search the GUID space to scrape the info in the event of an access control layer failure?

Comment: It looks like your answer is more simply (and generally), "yes, it's a bad idea, because your precautions could fail". But that's true for any situation. The question assumes the precautions are in place.